# Error while listing menu xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin

I have my menu where I have ten items, but when ready they do not appear completely, only the first letter of each item.

What can I do to solve it?

image
[image]

Code from my menu where I only have trouble displaying the text completely

```
private void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
{
    TabAdapter adapter = new TabAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment1(), "Início");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment2(), "Serviços");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment3(), "Cidade");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment4(), "Polícia");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment4(), "Cultura");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment4(), "Esporte");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment4(), "Geral");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment4(), "Caderno de esportes");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment4(), "Vedeos");
    adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment4(), "C Especiais");
    viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
}

public class TabAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public List<SupportFragment> Fragments { get; set; }
    public List<string> FragmentNames { get; set; }

    public TabAdapter (SupportFragmentManager sfm) : base (sfm)
    {
        Fragments = new List<SupportFragment>();
        FragmentNames = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddFragment(SupportFragment fragment, string name)
    {
        Fragments.Add(fragment);
        FragmentNames.Add(name);
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return Fragments.Count;
        }
    }

    public override SupportFragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        return Fragments[position];
    }

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.String(FragmentNames[position]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have in your `TabLayout` xml `app:tabMode="scrollable"` and `app:tabGravity="fill"`?

Comment: Yes ---- >  <Android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android: id = "+ id / tabs" android: layout_width = "match_parent" android: layout_height = "wrap_content" />

Comment: It worked, thank you

Comment: Great, I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `TabLayout` this line of code: `app:tabMode="scrollable"` so your code for `TabLayout` should look something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
  android:id = "@+id/tabs" 
  android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  app:tabGravity="fill"
  app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```